# How to store Asian language in json and show in Tkinter gui?

Tags: python, json, unicode, tkinter, southeast-asian-languages

I'm very new in Python programming. I want to store data in my language (Thai) in json file and then read it to show in Tkinter gui. Is there any Python package for help to read/write Asian language like my own ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3 you can read/write unicode.

for example

```
with open('path\to\file.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

from Tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
txt = Text(tk)
txt.pack()
txt.insert('1.0', data )
tk.mainloop()
```